# SAPUI5: Navigate to dynamically created view

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to dynamically create a view based on an existing view and then add the necessary routing/target. Currently I use the following code to achieve this:

```
var viewName = name + "View";
var targetName = name + "Target";
var routeName = name + "Route";

if (this.getRouter().getRoute(routeName) === undefined) {        
    console.log("create view");

    var view = sap.ui.view(({ viewName: "demo.view.Test", type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML }));
    this.getRouter().getTargets().getViews().setView(viewName, view);

    console.log("create target");

    this.getRouter().getTargets().addTarget(targetName, {
        viewName: viewName,
        viewPath: "demo.view",
        viewLevel: 2,
        parent: "base",
        controlId: "mainContainer",
        controlAggregation: "pages",
        title: name
    });

    console.log("create route");

    this.getRouter().addRoute({
        name: routeName,
        pattern: name,
        target: targetName
    });
};
```

However if I run this code (e.g. name = "Test2") and then try to navigate to the generated route, I get an error saying that the file containing the view could not be found (e.g. Test2.view.xml).

Is there a way to use this dynamically created view an a target without having a view file?

**Update**

The idea of creating an alias for a view to support multiple instances was taken from the UI5 documentation:
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.routing.Targets/constructor (refer to the viewName in the constructor)

Comment: Is Test2.view.xml being created or is this something you're stuck with? I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Basically I want to create multiple instances of the same view. The number of instances is not fixed (depends on the user), therefore I cannot create any view files in advance. Only the file Test.view.xml exists in the view directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since UI5 1.56 there is a new method [sap.ui.core.mvc.View.create](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.View/methods/sap.ui.core.mvc.View.create).

You could try something like this:

```
sap.ui.require(['sap/ui/core/mvc/View'],
   function(View){
     View.create({
       viewName: "demo.view.ViewToGetCloned",
       viewId: "demo.view.NameOfNewView",
       type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML
       }).then(function(oView) {
          ...    
       }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```